# Settlement data for Colombia to use in QGIS

Tags: geospatial, openstreetmap

Where can I find data about settlements to use in QGIS? I tried OpenStreetMap but can't find the data. I need it for Colombia.

Comment: If you're seeking data, OpenData.SE is the correct place to ask. Still, I suggest you add some details on what you're looking for exactly. Location? Extent? Names? Population? Have you tried official sources?